# mysql update with jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to update a mysql db from a textarea with jquery and ajax but cannot get the updated content of the text area to pass through to the php page.

I have a page and on the page I click a button which opens a layer and calls the edit_box function.

the layer then fills the form fields with data from the db.

the textarea is a nicedit box and all works well until I click save and any changes I have made to the textarea are not passed. Only the original content.

its seems so obvious but I cant seem to fathom the issue

any help appreciated

heres the code

html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
  #popupbox{ 
    padding:0;
    width: 99%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;   
    position:absolute;
    background: #FBFBF0; 
    border: solid #000000 2px; 
    z-index: 9000; 
    font-family: arial; 
    visibility: hidden; 
   }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
 <script>

 function get_edit_content(box_id,page_ref,template_ref)
   {
  $.get("get_content.php", { box_id: box_id, page_ref: page_ref, template_ref:template_ref } )
  .done(function(data) {
      document.getElementById("box_id").value = box_id; 
      document.getElementById("edit_content").value=data;
      var area1 = new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance("edit_content",{hasPanel : true});         
      });  
   }


   function edit_box(showhide,box_id,page_ref,template_ref){
     if(showhide == "show"){    
    get_edit_content(box_id,page_ref,template_ref);
            document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="visible";
     }else if(showhide == "hide"){
            document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="hidden";      
     }  
   }

  $(document).ready(function()
{    
      $('#sub').click(function (e) 
    { 
      e.preventDefault(); 
      $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'update_textarea.php', data:$('#myFrm').serialize(), success:
      function(response) 
        {
         alert(response);
        }
     });

   });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="popupbox">
  <form id="myFrm">
    <input type="hidden" name="page_ref" value="<? echo $page_ref; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="template_ref" value="<? echo $template_ref; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="box_id" name="box_id"/>
    <textarea name="edit_content" id="edit_content"  style="width: 500px; height:500px;"></textarea>
    <button id="sub" >Save</button>
    <center><a href="javascript:edit_box('hide');">close</a></center> 
  </form>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

php page

```
 <?
    include("connect.php"); 
$page_ref = $_POST['page_ref'];  
$template_ref = $_POST['template_ref'];
$box_id = $_POST['box_id'];
$edit_content = addslashes($_POST['edit_content']);  
if(mysql_query("UPDATE site_content SET content='$edit_content' WHERE page_ref='$page_ref' AND template_ref='$template_ref' AND box_id='$box_id' AND box_type='text'"))
    {
        echo "page_ref=".$page_ref." template_ref=".$template_ref." box_id=".$box_id." edit_content=".$edit_content;
    }
else
    {
        echo "error";
    }


   ?>
```

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok managed to solve the problem with this little snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#sub').click(function() {
   var edit_content = $('#myFrm').find('.nicEdit-main').text(); 
   var box_id = $('#myFrm').find("#box_id").val();
   var page_ref = $('#myFrm').find("#page_ref").val();
   var template_ref = $('#myFrm').find("#template_ref").val();
   $.post("update_textarea.php", {box_id:box_id, page_ref:page_ref, template_ref:template_ref, edit_content:edit_content },
  function(status){
   alert(status);       
   });
 });
});
```

I put the save button outside the form to stop the form being posted.

Answer (score 0):

It all looks ok at first sight, but try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE site_content SET content='$edit_content' WHERE page_ref='$page_ref' AND
template_ref='$template_ref' AND box_id='$box_id' AND box_type='text'";
echo "Query = $query <br />";
mysql_query($query);
```

This will output the query you are trying to run, and might help in debugging. Please try this, and post the result of the echo here.

Comment: Hi I updated the php page with your code and this was the returned output   " Query = UPDATE site_content SET content='    newtext  ' WHERE page_ref='170' AND
template_ref='15' AND box_id='10' AND box_type='text' <br />"  but the actual content of the box was "newtext bnvnvbsasas"

Comment: I find that if I remove the nicedit from the textarea then is psses through any updated text so its something to do with the nicedit

Comment: Yes Indeed, been trying out some stuff too, and it boils down to that. Get rid of nicedit I would say...

Comment: I cant I need a free rich text editor with all the features like changing font etc and it fits the bill. If I pass the form values therough to the php page not using ajax its fine its just when using the jquery ajax is when I have the problem, thats why I posted here to see if anyone can help me